# Convert large CSV file into NetCDF

Tags: csv, vector, machine-learning, netcdf

I'd like to convert the file of float vector data written in CSV format which consists of 3 million rows and 150 columns like the following into NetCDF format.

```
0.3,0.9,1.3,0.5,...,0.9
-5.1,0.1,1.0,8.4,...,6.7
...
```

First, I tried something like *cache-all-the-data-and-then-convert-it* algorithm, but it didn't work because it could not allocate the memory for the cache.
So I need the code written in *convert-one-by-one* algorithm.

Does any one know such solutions?

The memory capacity of my machine is 8 MiB, and it's OK for any programming language such as C, Java, and Python.

Comment: Do you want to store all of that data as a single 3 million x 150 two dimensional variable?

Answer (score 0):

With python you can read the file line by line.

```
with open("myfile.csv") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        appendtoNetcdf(line)
```

So you dont have to load all the file contents into memory.

Check the [netCDF4-python library](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python), you can create a netcdf4 or many netcdf4 files easily.